# Nginx subdomain issue nginx tries to get files from the subdomain's parent httpdocs

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I am trying to make a subdomain (for the purposes of this question: `grace.myexample.com`) using nginx.

The configuration is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 10.10.185.163:80;

    server_name grace.myexample.com;
    server_name www.grace.myexample.com;
    server_name ipv4.grace.myexample.com;


    client_max_body_size 128m;

    location / { # IPv6 isn't supported in proxy_pass yet.
        proxy_pass http://10.10.185.163:7080;

        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /internal-nginx-static-location/ {
        alias      /var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/grace/;
        access_log /var/www/vhosts/grace.example.com/statistics/logs/proxy_access_log;
        add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;
        internal;
    }
}
```

When I go to my subdomain, it is trying to load the files from the root domain's httpdocs (e.g. `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs`)

Answer (score 0):

Given your upstream server **sends it back** (here you are setting headers in the request message sent **by nginx to** the relevant upstream server), this :

```
proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
```

should be :

```
proxy_set_header X-Accel-Redirect /internal-nginx-static-location;
```

See [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ignore_headers) referencing special headers interpreted by nginx when present in an upstream's **response** message.